# No word break in two floating divs

Tags: html, css, html-table

```
<table class="project-table">
        <thead>
            <tr class="align-top">
                <td class="short-col heading">Project Name</td>
                <td class="short-col heading align-center">Project Id</td>
                <td class="short-col heading">Date &amp; Time</td>
                <td class="short-col heading">Student</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>


                <tr class="bottom-row-dashed">
                    <td class="long-col">
                            <div class="achievement-box float-left">Winner</div>

                        <div class="float-left margin-left">Intrusion Detection System in Cloud Architecture</div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="short-col align-center">1</td>
                    <td class="short-col">01 Apr 2014, 09:30 PM</td>
                    <td class="short-col">Sayan Chowdhury</td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
        </tr></tbody>
    </table>
```

[image: table pic]

The stylus file:

```
table.project-table
    font-size: 13px
    margin-top: 10px
    width: 100%
    border-collapse: collapse
    .bottom-row-dashed
        border-bottom: 1px dashed border-color

    .margin-right
        margin-right: 2px
    .margin-left
        margin-left: 2px

    td
        &.short-col
            width: 1%
        &.large-col
            width: 20%
        &.medium-col
            width: 10%
    tr
        &.align-top
            vertical-align: top
```

The div that contains "Winner" and "Intrusion Detection System in Cloud Architecture" are float left. I added `word-wrap:break-word;` but it did not help breaking the breaking the term "Intrusion Detection System in Cloud Architecture". The `short-col` and `long-col` class defines the width of the table column

How can I break the term "Intrusion Detection System in Cloud Architecture" based on the width.?

EDIT: I want to have "Intrusion Detection System in Cloud Architecture" and "Winner" on the same line but as the word should break off in the middle based on the width

Comment: Post your css. If you can, post a jfiddle.

Comment: and there is a typo <tr calss="align-top"> class

Comment: Have a go at using `max-width` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check out the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J36h4/1/)

I just added a break 
 tag

```
 <div class="float-left margin-left">Intrusion Detection<br> System in Cloud Architecture</div>
```

### Output fiddle

[image: Output]

### Another way

[Another way of Doing it](http://jsfiddle.net/J36h4/2/)

Setting  of max width does the trick

```
 th{
     padding-left:30px;
    }
    td{
     padding-left:30px;
          max-width: 200px; /*or whatever*/
      word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    th:first-child{
        padding-left:0px;
    }
    td:first-child{
        padding-left:0px;
    }
```

[image: Output next]

### Output using word wrap and max-width

[Check this out latest](http://jsfiddle.net/J36h4/4/)

```
 display:inline;
```

Comment: I want to have "Winner" and "Intrusion Detection System in Cloud Architecture" in the same line. When the project name is short it does come in same line but goes to next line when the project name is big.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Give some width to the first td of first row like:
Check the demo:[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/95vvP/)

```
<table class="project-table">
        <thead>
            <tr calss="align-top">
                <td class="short-col heading" width="200px">Project Name</td>
                <td class="short-col heading align-center">Project Id</td>
                <td class="short-col heading">Date &amp; Time</td>
                <td class="short-col heading">Student</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>


                <tr class="bottom-row-dashed">
                    <td class="long-col" >
                            <div class="achievement-box float-left">Winner</div>

                        <div class="float-left margin-left">Intrusion Detection System in Cloud Architecture</div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="short-col align-center">1</td>
                    <td class="short-col">01 Apr 2014, 09:30 PM</td>
                    <td class="short-col">Sayan Chowdhury</td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
        </tr></tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I want to have "Winner" and "Intrusion Detection System in Cloud Architecture" in the same line. When the project name is short it does come in same line but goes to next line when the project name is big.

Comment: Eta kaaj korbe. You are just specifying that column width. If the content is wider than that column width, it will automatically wrap.